# Does EOS have a standard currency symbol (like the $ for dollars)?

Tags: naming

Does EOS have a currency symbol that's widely used such as ฿ for bitcoin or $ for the USD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOS does not have a typography currency symbol analog.  It is simply 'EOS'. You will often see the chestahedron logo alongside (or in place of) 'EOS'.